# Bash Script Leet Text Convertor: How to get array to recognize spaces

Tags: arrays, bash, space

The issue with the code below is that I can not seem to get the array to recognize when the text has spaces in it or not. I figured adding the ' ' value in the array would handle this, but I was wrong. I haven't found much luck from searches about how to get an array to recognize spaces in bash scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-e" ]; then # if the cli argument is -e
    OPT="encrypt"; # set the option to encrypt
elif [ "$1" == "-d" ]; then # if the cli argument is -d
    OPT="decrypt"; # set the option to decrypt
else # else show the proper usage
    echo "Usage - Encrypt text: ./l33t.sh -e text";
    echo "Usage - Decrypt text: ./l33t.sh -d text";
    exit;
fi
#creating an array for leet text and plain text
declare -a LEET=('ɐ' 'ß' '©' 'Ð' '€' 'ƒ' '&' '#' 'I' '¿' 'X' '£' 'M' '?' 'ø' 'p' 'O' 'Я' '§' '†' 'µ' '^' 'W' '×' '¥' 'z' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '0' ' ');
declare -a ENG=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '0' ' ');
echo -n "Please enter a string to $OPT: "; # asking for user input
read INPUT; # grab the input
while read letter; # for each character in the input (check the grep near done)
do
    for i in {0..37} # for each item in the array
    do
            if [ "$OPT" == "encrypt" ]; then # if the option is set to encrypt
                    FIND=${ENG[$i]}; # the array to look through is the plain array
            elif [ "$OPT" == "decrypt" ]; then # else the array to look through is the leet text array
                    FIND=${LEET[$i]};
            fi

            if [ "$OPT" == "encrypt" ]; then # if the option is set to encrypt
                    if [ "$FIND" == "$letter" ]; then # if our character is in the plain array
                            ENCRYPTED+=${LEET[$i]}; # Add to Encrypted that values leet transformation
                    fi
            elif [ "$OPT" == "decrypt" ]; then # else do the same thing except with oposite arrays
                    if [ "$FIND" == "$letter" ]; then
                            ENCRYPTED+=${ENG[$i]};
                    fi
            fi
    done
done < <(grep -o . <<< $INPUT)
echo $ENCRYPTED; # echo the result
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
while read letter
```

to

```
while IFS= read -r letter
```

Otherwise, the read command ignores leading and trailing whitespace. That's kind of crucial when you're trying to read a space.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed! The little things, the little things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which part you make the comparison but I think quoting your variable ENCRYPTED would also be helpful:

```
echo "$ENCRYPTED"
```

I also don't see any part of the code where a possible instance to a comparison with space could be a problem.

Add: You only have 37 elements so the loop should also be only from 0 to 36:

```
for i in {0..36} # for each item in the array
```

Probably that's something that makes you append an empty character.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using tr (man tr for more details, naturally).